# QSqlQueryModel doesn't work

Tags: sql, database, qt, authentication, qsqlquery

I have a QSqlDatabase:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("something");
db.setUserName("username");
db.setPassword("password");
```

(I can log in in MySQL Workbench with the password and username i'm using, so i think they are correct.)

```
QSqlDatabase::database().open();
```

It returns true, so the opening succeeded. But the next code doesn't work:

```
QSqlQueryModel* model = new QSqlQueryModel();
model->setQuery("select user_id, name, password, level from user where user_id = 'user' and password = 'password'");
```

Now the `model->rowCount` is equal to 0 (i don't know why) and

```
model->index(0, 0).data() == "username" &&
            model->index(0, 2).data() == "password"
```

returns false. Does anybody know what could be the problem here?

Comment: are you sure your `user` table is not empty? are you sure there is at least one row in the table where `user_id` is *`user`* and `password` is *`password`*? try executing your query in MySQL Workbench and see if it has results. . .

Answer (score 0):

`QSqlQueryModel` will work after you have create query, execute it and then make `setQuery()`. I think you forgot create query and `exec()` it.

So:

```
QSqlQuery query;
if(query.exec("select user_id, name, password, level from user where user_id = 'user' and password = 'password'"))
    model->setQuery(query);
```

If you want to update model you can use:

```
model->query()->exec();
model->setQuery(model->query());
```

My advice - make your own class from `QSqlQueryModel` and do what you want with less code.

Comment: I must use QSqlQueryModel and according to the QT documentation my code is correct. :(

Comment: Your code is not correct since you did not execute the query. The Doc clearly states that the model will consume the ACTIVE query. The query is only active if it was EXECUTED.

Comment: @OnWhenReady , the code he posted is correct, he is using [`QSqlQueryModel::setQuery(const QString& query)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#setQuery-1) not [`QSqlQueryModel::setQuery(const QSqlQuery& query)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#setQuery).

Comment: Thats funny. The time i answered the code was completely different. Anyway. It's a trivial thing. Use a query, execute it and set it. Simple.